# Capping the bit rate of an HLS stream programmatically on iOS devices

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I have an HD video that I am streaming to an iOS app.  I want to allow the user the ability to cap the max stream quality (low, medium, high) considering the video is several GBs when streaming at the max bit rate.  Along the same lines, I would like to automatically choose a setting based on cellular vs wifi connection, for the obvious data-cap reasons.

I have no problem getting the current bit rate by accessing the `AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent`, but am lost when it comes to forcing a lower quality stream.

Is this even possible with HLS?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly dynamic, but I did solve this problem by creating four different m3u8 playlists. I labeled each playlist to represent a stream quality (low, medium, high, extreme). The user would select one based on the desired max quality. The extreme playlist includes the URLs of all qualities. The high playlist has less URLs than the extreme, the medium less URLs than the high, and the low less URLs than the medium.  Whenever the user selects a different quality, I would just switch the base stream playlist to the respective quality playlist URL.

Here is a simple example of the four different playlists.

**HLS_Movie_Extreme.m3u8**

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=64000
stream-0-64000/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
stream-1-350000/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=800000
stream-2-800000/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1200000
stream-3-1200000/index prog_index.m3u8 m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1800000
stream-4-1800000/prog_index.m3u8
```

**HLS_Movie_High.m3u8**

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=64000
stream-0-64000/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
stream-1-350000/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=800000
stream-2-800000/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1200000
stream-3-1200000/index prog_index.m3u8 m3u8
```

**HLS_Movie_Medium.m3u8**

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=64000
stream-0-64000/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
stream-1-350000/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=800000
stream-2-800000/prog_index.m3u8
```

**HLS_Movie_Low.m3u8**

```
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=64000
stream-0-64000/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
stream-1-350000/prog_index.m3u8
```

Like I said, it's not dynamic, but you could use various techniques to get the users network connection and point to the desired quality playlist if needed.  For me, it was sufficient to get the user's preference, and adjust the stream accordingly.

Comment: How do you select particular stream from m3u8 file, can you share a code snippet please ? Thanks!

Comment: @Romk1n I haven't worked on this code for a while, so I don't have a code snippet handy. It's basically the same as stopping the current stream, and starting a new one at the same time as the first. The playlist that you are switching to will be using the same HLS files, you're just making higher quality ones available. So take the player time before switching streams, switch streams, and begin playing from that time. Hope that helps!

Comment: @timgcarlson, suggested aproach completely reset the player, and from app we have to remember the current playback time to seek to same  position after resetting with desired bitrates. There is a chance that player might show blank until it loads it. Is there any other better approach

Answer (score 5):

If you are using AVPlayer, the right way should be

```
preferredPeakBitRate
```

From Apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1388541-preferredpeakbitrate), The desired limit, in bits per second, of network bandwidth consumption for this item.

Comment: can you guild me how to use preferredPeakBitRate. can you provide demo code.

Comment: @Wizard of iOS,Yes I need the demo also if you have.

Comment: what is the value we have to pass for 360,720,1080 and Auto for this function